# Spring Security fullyAuthenticated() and hasRole("ADMIN")

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to secure my application so that some URLs are accessible to anybody fully authenthicated and `admin` URL to be accessible to admin user, fully authenticated as well.

But right now, I can't manage to find a way to use `fullyAuthenticaded() AND hasrole()` together.

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/api/**", "/health")
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/get-data").fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write something like this:

> antMatchers("/api/get-data").access("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_BANNED')")

This is like you are writing the access when you define in xml file. Its same thing here.

Now you can define some url for one antMatches with only isFullyAuthenticated and some url for another antMatches with admin role and isFullyAuthenticated.

For more clarification read [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868027/spring-security-allow-page-views-for-all-fully-authenticated-users-unless-they).